# Autofilling Vertex Properties in GraphMappingConfig

Tags: amazon-web-services, graph-databases, amazon-neptune, aws-dms

I am Using AWS DMS to migrate schemas from MySQL to an AWS Neptune graph database. Part of this process is writing a [GraphMappingConfig.json](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/dms-neptune-graph-mapping.html) file. There isn't much documentation, but I am wondering, is there is a way to implicitly define vertex properties from the column names and values?

For example, I don't want to have to write a separate "vertex_property" object for each property, because I have many tables and dozens of columns on each table. Instead, I suspect that there should be a way to encode that I want vertex properties to be built as {column_name: column_value} ranging over all columns except the table's id column.

Comment: As it stands today, you'll need to explicitly define each column that you want to bring over into a vertex property (similar with columns from join tables that you want to bring over as edge properties) within the JSON mapping file.  You could write a script to build the JSON and that is something that we've discussed providing to customers.  Just need to get back around to working on that. :)

Comment: Thanks Taylor. If you want to copy and paste that comment as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands today, you'll need to explicitly define each column that you want to bring over into a vertex property (similar with columns from join tables that you want to bring over as edge properties) within the JSON mapping file. You could write a script to build the JSON and that is something that we've discussed providing to customers. Just need to get back around to working on that. :)